# How to connect Mongo DB with user and password but without database name in Java

Tags: java, mongodb

I am doing Mongo DB Java side development and want to connect to Mongo DB instance. I read the authentication part from this link http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.0/driver/reference/connecting/authenticating/. And it has below method to be used for authentication.

```
MongoCredential credential = MongoCredential.createCredential(user,
                                                              database,
                                                              password);
```

The above code works fine but I need to know the database name first. How to connect to Mongo DB without specifying database? I want to connect to it and return the list of databases for users to select.

Comment: The database here has nothing to do the database you want to work on. It's the source for authentication. "database - the database where the user is defined".

Comment: I am still not getting you. When trying to connect to Mongo DB, what is the value of database I should use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned here, authentication in MongoDB is always does against a source - which can be external - but it is usually a database name.

Whenever you create a user, it is saved in a special collection called `system.users` in the `admin` db. Thus, the `admin` db is implicitly created when you create you first user.

When you want to list your databases, whether it's via a shell helper `show dbs` or database driver, the `listDatabases` command is being called behind the scenes.

If you enable authentication, in order to execute this command, you must be a user with a predefined (or custom) role which include the `listDatabases` privileged actions.

There are few builtin xxxAnyDatabase roles - such as `readAnyDatabase` role -which include the `listDatabases` privileged action.

If you want to create a user with any of the xxxAnyDatabase roles, it must be done in the **admin database**.

So, to make a long story short, if you want to list databases:

1. Your only option is the `admin` database as the authentication source
2. The user must have an adequate role: `readAnyDatabase`, `readWriteAnyDatabase`, `dbAdminAnyDatabase` (or a super user role such as `root`)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot connect without specifying a database, as users are DEFINED on a database. If you have not explicitly chosen a database where you created your user, the correct (default) database name is "admin".

Thus:

```
MongoCredential credential = MongoCredential.createCredential("myuser",
                                                          "admin",
                                                          "secret");
```

... should do the job.

Answer (score -1):

```
mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=com.mkyong.core -DartifactId=mongodb -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-quickstart -DinteractiveMode=false
```